# Create agent job from power shell script with including of power shell command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-agent

I try to automate SQL Server 2016 installation process by using power shell scripting. When I execute Invoke-SqlCmd with parameter of file:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "..\res\test.sql" -ServerInstance "(local)" -Database "master" -ErrorAction Stop
```

which include agent job create script with power shell command:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Erase Phantom System Health Records.', 
    @step_id=3, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'PowerShell', 
    @command=N'if (''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(INST))'' -eq ''MSSQLSERVER'') {$a = ''\DEFAULT''} ELSE {$a = ''''};
       (Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))$a).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
```

it`s stops with error:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd : 'INST' scripting variable not defined
```

Obviously this is $ character which I need to escape before creation. Have anybody idea about how to do this? I searched, but can`t find anything that work.

Comment: I can see no fault in that script. The SQL interpreter will convert the two successive single quotes into single quotes which will prevent PowerShell from interpreting the `$` sign. The `ESCAPE_SQUOTE` is also correct, it will replace any single quotes in the instance name with two single quotes, which PowerShell then converts back to a single single quote. So if nothing else changes that `EXEC` command inside the sql script, I can only conclude that somehow your job agent doesn't know about the `INST` variable - which has been around since SQL 2005 ...

Comment: The problem is conclude in sql cmd itself. If we execute script in mmc - all fine, if we switch it in SqlCmd-mode (mode that uses by Invoke-SqlCmd) - it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Disable variables for InvokeSQLcmd

`Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "..\res\test.sql" -ServerInstance "(local)" -Database "master" -ErrorAction Stop -DisableVariables`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is trying to parse your `$(ESCAPE_xxxx(yyyy))` blocks, so you'll need to escape those before you send it to Invoke-SqlCmd. The easiest way to do that is going to be [the `replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator):

```
$script = Get-Content "..\res\test.sql"
$script -replace '\(ESCAPE_(\w+)\((.+)\)\)','`(ESCAPE_$1`($2`)`)'
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile $script -ServerInstance "(local)" -Database "master" -ErrorAction Stop
```

Obviously, you won't be able to just escape every parenthetical in a block of SQL commands, but you can do some experimentation to find out how narrow or broad this replacement needs to be.